# Migrate SQLite db from Xamarin Android to NET Maui app?

Tags: android, sqlite, maui

I'm in the process to release a NET Maui upgrade to my existing Xamarin Android app but as my users already have an SQLite DB I need to be able up upgrade the app and retain the DB. My Xamarin app is using SQLiteOpenHelper and getting the user version  @"PRAGMA user_version" = 8, but when I run the same query in the Maui app, I get 0 as user_version.

I have verified that I'm using the same connection string on both apps which is `Data Source=/data/user/0/<my app id>/databases/my_database.db`.

```
    public partial class BaseHandler : Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private const string DB_NAME = "my_database.db";
        Android.Content.Context _context;

        private Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteDatabase _db = null;
        public BaseHandler (IContext context) : base (context.AppContext, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION)
        {
            _context = context.AppContext;
            _db = WritableDatabase; 
            var version = ExecuteScalar(@"PRAGMA user_version");
        }

        public override void OnCreate (Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            var sqls = this.CreateDatabaseSql();
            this.DoSql(db, sqls);
            var version = ExecuteScalar(@"PRAGMA user_version");
        }
```

The Maui app uses the sqlite-net-pcl package

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyItem>> GetAllItems()
        {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM MY_ITEMS;";

            try
            {
                await using var cnn = GetCnn();
                return await cnn.QueryAsync<MyItem>(sql);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you can access the db with its path directly, if its not already created, create one!

Comment: I'm not really sure how your answer helps? My problem is that I have an existing Xamarin app installed (e.g. MyApp v1.0) but my new version is created in Maui and replaces the existing app (e.g. MyApp v2.0) and the data that was created with v1 should be used, and not replaced, by the v2 app but the database is not recognized/found. App Id is identical so that app is replaced on the device but I also need to use the existing already created database.

Comment: Does it have a different bundle id? Also i haven't answered anything i am commenting to understand things better

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe that "BundleId" is what IOS calls what Android calls "ApplicationId" and I refer to above as "app id". Yes, they are the same between the Xamarin and Maui app.

Comment: If that is the case make sure your path is correct and you should be able to access the database